# How to choose the encode of a file created by SmbFileOutputStream?

Tags: encoding

I am using a method to create a file in a specific path in a shared folder inside my local net.

```
public static void stringToArquivoTextoRemoto(String path, String fileName, String content, NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth) {
            String absolutePath = path + File.separator + fileName;
            try {
                    jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.disablePlainTextPasswords", "false");
                    SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(absolutePath, auth);
                    SmbFileOutputStream smbFileOutputStream = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile);
                    smbFileOutputStream.write(content.getBytes());
                    smbFileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SmbException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Now, I am trying to change the encode from "UTF-8" to "ISO-8859-1".
I already tried to put:

```
jcifs.Config.setProperty( "jcifs.encoding", "ISO-8859-1" );
```

But it didn't work.

I found a lot of information about how to change the encode using the FileOutputStream, but I found nothing about this using SmbFileOutputStream.

What do I need to do to choose the encode of a file created by SmbFileOutputStream?

Answer (score 1):

This will solve the issue:

```
package fileWriting;

import java.io.IOException;

import jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFile;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream;

public class testWriting {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String user = "domain;username:password";
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(user);
        String path = "smb://shared/Projects/test.txt";
        SmbFile sFile = new SmbFile(path, auth);
        try (SmbFileOutputStream sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(sFile)) {
            String v = "Test for file writing!";
            byte[] utf = v.getBytes("UTF-8");
            byte[] latin1 = new String(utf, "UTF-8").getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
            sfos.write(latin1,0,latin1.length );
        }
    }
}
```